# Updating cell value to null in Cassandra and avoid tombstones

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, tombstone

We are having DSE 6.8 with Cassandra version **3.11** and ysing `spring-data-cassandra 2.2.6` which is using `cassandra-driver-core 3.7.2`

We have use cases where we need to **UPDATE** a field (cell) value to null (or whatever will represent "no value"), and it was not null before.

The trick here is that we wanted to avoid tombstones when applying this operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible - in Cassandra, setting value to `null` is equal to deletion operation that will generate a tombstone. If you want to avoid a tombstone, agree on some artificial value that will represent "no value", like, empty string, 0, etc.